# Text not wrapping in Slick Slider

Tags: jquery, css

I want to implement a carousel with slick slider, showing an image and text at the bottom of it, followed by some large dots that indicate that there is more.

Now there are two problems I am facing:

1. The text does not wrap
2. The dots on the bottom are almost invisible

The implementation is pretty basic:

```
    $( document ).ready(function(condition) {
        // show user opinion carrusel
        $(\'.user_opinions\').slick({
            dots: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 3
        });
    });
```

html

```
    <div class="user_opinions" style="position: relative; outline: 0; width: 100% !important;">
      <div style="">
            <img src="/g/p/user_1.png" width="100%" alt="">
            <div style=" margin: 10px;">
              <p style="">Es sind definitiv die Filter die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die bla finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
              <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
              <strong>Jens K</srong>
            </div>

      </div>
      <div>
            <img src="/g/p/user2.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
            <div style=" margin: 10px;">
              <p>Es sind definitiv die Filter auf x die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die blub finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
              <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
              <strong>Jens K</srong>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

How can I make the text wrap and how to enlarge the dots?

Comment: Did you only use inline styles or is there an external css?

Answer (score 3):

I've included the CDNs in my example below using your code - seems to be working fine. Have you included all the relevant stylesheets/scripts?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show user opinion carrusel
  $('.user_opinions').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<div class="user_opinions" style="position: relative; outline: 0; width: 100% !important;">
  <div style="">
    <img src="/g/p/user_1.png" width="100%" alt="">
    <div style=" margin: 10px;">
      <p style="">Es sind definitiv die Filter die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die bla finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
      <strong>Jens K</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/g/p/user2.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
    <div style=" margin: 10px;">
      <p>Es sind definitiv die Filter auf x die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die blub finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
      <strong>Jens K</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

I have amended a spelling error in your `strong` tag, and removed some characters from your `.js` file as they weren't necessary for the example.

You can change the size of the dots by increasing the `font-size` of `.slick-dots li button:before` in your CSS file, and the `color` here too.

Here's an example with styled dots:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show user opinion carrusel
  $('.user_opinions').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

```css
.slick-dots li button:before {
  font-size: 15px !important;
  color: #10bdb7 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<div class="user_opinions" style="position: relative; outline: 0; width: 100% !important;">
  <div style="">
    <img src="/g/p/user_1.png" width="100%" alt="">
    <div style=" margin: 10px;">
      <p style="">Es sind definitiv die Filter die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die bla finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
      <strong>Jens K</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="/g/p/user2.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
    <div style=" margin: 10px;">
      <p>Es sind definitiv die Filter auf x die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die blub finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
      <strong>Jens K</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div>
    <img src="/g/p/user2.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
    <div style=" margin: 10px;">
      <p>Es sind definitiv die Filter auf x die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die blub finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
      <strong>Jens K</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div>
    <img src="/g/p/user2.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
    <div style=" margin: 10px;">
      <p>Es sind definitiv die Filter auf x die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die blub finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
      <strong>Jens K</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div>
    <img src="/g/p/user2.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
    <div style=" margin: 10px;">
      <p>Es sind definitiv die Filter auf x die es einfach machen. Ich kann genau die blub finden nach der ich gesucht habe.</p>
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
      <strong>Jens K</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Found the problem. I had a class defined within a .css called .draggable{} with nowrap. That was causing this issue.

Comment: Regarding the dots, I found that this error might be related to the small dot size. Is this possible, and if, how to solve that? Access to font at 'http://static.rex.rex/app_global/slick/fonts/slick.ttf' from origin 'http://rex.watchgurus' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Solved the dots problematic. Just to let other know that are searching for the same thing. I needed to change my static nginx server configuration to allow woff and ttf files by adding this line to the file location config:  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *; That solved the problem for android, on iOS somehow it was never an issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this css rule on your p (or add a class)

```
p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```